# Getting the error in the autocomplete function of the jquery "this.source is not a function."

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-ajax

My code is :

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://url.com",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                //$("#id").autocomplete({ source: response });
                $("#search").autocomplete(
           {
               source: data,
               select: function (event, ui) {
                   $("#search").val(ui.item.FirstName + " / " + ui.item.LastName);
                   return false;
               }
           }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
               return $("<li></li>")
                   .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                   .append("<a><strong>" + item.FirstName + "</strong> / " + item.LastName + "</a>")
                   .appendTo(ul);
           };
            }
        });
```

The data in the url is of the form
{{Data: Array[22], Id: null, Result: Object}

I want to use the FirstName and LastName of the Array which is of the form

```
{FirstNam:R , LAstName:e , Id:9 },{FirstNam:R , LAstName:e , Id:9},...
```

I tried this also

```
$.getJSON("https://url.com", function (json) {
                console.log(json);    

            });
```

But this also gives the same error.

Any help ??

I have tried this also

```
  $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://url.com",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                         return {
                            label: item.FirstName,
                            id: item.LastName 

                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#search').val(ui.item.label);
                      }
    });
```

this not even working

Answer (score 0):

Try `data.d` as source.
Like this:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
   source: data.d,
});
```

just `data` is an object but `data.d` makes it into a readable string or something similar.

Also, you shouldn't use the success function because it's been deprecated by jQuery since 1.8, instead use this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://url.com",
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data){
  console.log(data.d);
});
```

Comment: Still getting the same error after the chage..Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function

Comment: I am using  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js"></script> from the nuget